# Parsing XML with XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have the following XML format that has 100 items as the below

I want to parse it and extract data1 and data2 how can i do this with [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) Perl module

```
<Item>
<data1>  <data3> date </data3> </data1>
<data2>   data2 </data2>

</Item>
<Item>
<data1>  <date3> data22 </data3> </data1>
<data2>   data2 </data2>
</Item>
....
```

Comment: That isn't well-formed XML and can't be parsed by an XML parser. If you change `<\element>` to `</element>` throughout, it will be OK. After reading http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.38/Twig.pm what have you tried?

Comment: -1 for claiming it is XML when it is not XML.

Answer (score 4):

Your XML does not conform specification, so no parser could process it as it is. Main problems are:

- XML is case-sensitive, so `Item` is something else than `item`
- closing tags start with slash, not backslash
- there should be top-level element

Fixing those issues, this code works:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $data = <<END_DATA;
<items>
    <item>
        <data1>   data1 </data1>
        <data2>   data2 </data2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <data1>   data1 </data1>
        <data2>   data2 </data2>
    </item>
</items>
END_DATA


my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'item' => sub {
            # process each item and print contents of dataN elements
            print
                $_->first_child_trimmed_text('data1'), "\t",
                $_->first_child_trimmed_text('data2'),"\n";
        },
    },
)->parse($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,sorry I updated my question in the same time you wrote the answer.

Comment: @Rubin - you can access descendant items like this: `eval { $_->first_descendant('data3')->trimmed_text }`. I think your best bet is to play with example I posted and look [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) docs for methods description.